# What are the difficulties of replacing the UN with a new, similar organization but without veto powers?

Tags: united-nations, unsc

The UN Security Council can not act against Russia as they use their veto on any resolution against their invasion. It seems obvious that we need a reformation of the council so no country can block such a resolution one-sided. However, that is not possible as Russia would need to approve that reform, too, which it won't do.

So if we can't reform it, can't we create a new organization similar to the UN? In my imagination, all states could leave the UN, establish "UN 2.0" (leaving Russia as the last and only member of the old UN), and come up with a resolution in that new organization that would legitimate international intervention, alongside a security council without veto permissions.

I know it can't be that easy, but I'm wondering what the blocker would be for this. Is there a reason why this idea is not pursued or discussed?

Comment: The veto is a feature, not a bug. The theory is that the only way to get the world's major powers in the same room at the same time is to ensure that none of them can override the wishes of the others. It means that the UN is often powerless to act; but the idea is that a weak UN that everyone attends nonetheless reduces the chances of war between the major powers. Also, the UN _is_ the second attempt; see the [League of Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations) for the first one.

Comment: It´s not like Russia is the only country using the veto right, USA also using it.

Comment: You forgot China. Let's skip straight to UN 3.0.

Comment: "I know it can't be that easy.." How do you know that? I think it surely is that easy, you just have to want to do it and you could do it.

Comment: @HK-51 Russia and China would be not the only countries unhepy with UN X.0 dominated by the West.

Comment: The question of reforming the UN is not possible on this site.  But you need to re-examine your framing *... leaving Russia the last and only member of the old UN*.  Just look at the the most recent attempt to get a condemnation from the UNSC.  Apart from the veto, there were 4 abstentions from 3 continents. If you look deeper into these you'll see these abstentions are more representative than coincidental.  Nobody likes Ukrainians being pointlessly killed.  But people aware of what's happening also know where the instigation [comes from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ft_8knDiJxA&t=2790s)

Comment: Dont get me wrong its urgent -- by some accounts we may be in our [last week](https://twitter.com/Ukraine66251776/status/1576494751523942400)

Comment: @Raveesh You're right. I think China and Russia are still the worse actors, but the UN 4.0 would definitely have to drop the US.

Comment: The established nuclear powers, and in particular the USA would **never ever** join an organisation in which they didn't have a veto. Perhaps after WWIII, and after the USA has ceased to exist ... until then this is a non-starter.

Comment: "new organization that would legitimate international intervention, alongside a security council without veto permissions": So...something like NATO: an international organisation [with no veto](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_49178.htm) that can take collective military action against other countries. Already contains 3 of the UN veto countries...but obviously only covers countries in Europe and North America.

Comment: @JamesK I think it's quite possible they'll join, they just won't enforce anything that UN 3.0 decides - which would render it a toothless organization anyway.

Comment: You misunderstand the veto: it's not "let's give these groups special rights" but rather "these groups would wipe us off the map if they didn't like us, so they already have special rights and we should probably just acknowledge that and move on instead of trying to convince them to give them up"

Answer (score 2):

Just so we can close this question as answered: because the new organization would not be a replacement for the UN - it's extremely unlikely the major powers would join if not for a veto.

And the "major powers" are not the 4 existing permanent members besides Russia. Within the current UN, there's been an on-going discussion that India and/or Brazil should have a permanent position as well. That discussion has been stalled for pretty much the same reason; you can't just rewrite the rules of the existing UN. For for a UN 3.0? India would want the same status as China, and Pakistan has its own ideas about India in turn, and ...

It just becomes too much of a mess setting up such an alternative. Probably the only thing you could get away with is some kind of "United Democracies", which would *not* replace the UN, and which would exclude China and Russia for obvious reasons.